# How ModelState.IsValid works in asp.net webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

i am new to Asp.net. I have a model that have some attributes like `[Required]`

```
public class UserNamePasswordModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Now here is my simple controller method

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(UserNamePasswordModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState); // debugger is not comming come here.
}
```

As i have provided the `Annotations` on ***Email*** and ***ConfirmPassword*** but when i making a request to Register end point then `Modelstate.IsValid` should be `false` but it is not the case.
So somewhere should i add some code to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i got my answer actually my Models classes are in different project and i just got to know that **Data-Annotations are not portable** so **ModelState.IsValid** is not able to see the those annotations and hence returning true every time.
Hope it helps somebody.
If want to do model state validation then make corresponding to models with different name and add annotation in the latter class like:-

**Model**:- in your portable class library.

```
public class AddPasswordModel 
{
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

**Same Model class but with annotations in your project.**

```
public class AddPasswordModelServer 
{
    [Required]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Now tell your project that which kind of metadata that AddPasswordModel is going to use so that we can use annotations.
Now in you **Global.asax** class's **Application_start()** add this code.

```
TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(AddPasswordModel),
                                   typeof(AddPasswordModelServer)),
                                   typeof(AddPasswordModel));
```

Now you are all set to use Data-annotations on your models that is present in a portable library. Hope it help someone.